# What's the easiest way to always round a number down in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I can't seem to find this anywhere, but what is the correct way to always round a number down, to a specific decimal precision, using SQL Server 2005?

Will I need to write my own function or is there already a function that does this?

I do know that SQL Server 2008 R2 has a `ROUNDDOWN` function, and it does exactly what I need.    Does a similar function exist in 2005?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Rounding down* to a specific decimal place is the same as *truncating* to a decimal place... and you can use [`round()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to do this:

```
select round(123.456789, 4, 1)
```

Returns:

```
123.456700
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the trick.  Now I need to just wait 60 more seconds to give you the answer mark.

Comment: This won't work for negative values because truncating negative values means rounding up.

Answer (score 3):

Try FLOOR. Google "sql server 2005 floor"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: 'to a specific decimal precision'

Comment: FLOOR could work, so long as I monkey with the data bit.  i.e. `FLOOR(MyValue * 100) / 100` should get me what I need for 2 decimal precision.  This may be the best answer that I have.  I always hate to use these types of tricks IF an integrated solution exists.

Comment: I missed that part apparently

Comment: @RLH If you know the data will never be over 2 decimals in precision yes, if all you care about is the 2nd decimal why not cast as a string and truncate from the third decimal on?  Except that would be costly cycle-wise...

Comment: This is a less than usual case. Specifically, our sales are paid off of commissions, which is derived from a certain percent of various goals. In this case, if you are trying to get to, say, a 50% sales tier, the factor I'm comparing needs to be .50 or greater. It cannot be .499999 because that would put the sale in the .49 tier. If a seller feels like they should be in a higher tier due to some extraneous circumstance, the manager must override the calculation. However, it is the job of the processing application to calculate the numbers just as they are. There's no grace in code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [FLOOR()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) ? (30 char minimum)